# nodejs, pgSQL and Async queries

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am new to nodejs and I am trying to fetch some data from my PG server. I manage to get my data but not in the order I expected. I may not use it the proper way, can anyone help ?

Here is a sample of code :

```
var pg = require('pg');

var db = new pg.Client(conString);
var link = db.connect();

var data = {};

// -----
console.log(prefix+'Fetching categories');
db.query('SELECT DISTINCT category FROM cc WHERE category IS NOT NULL', function(err, data){
    data.rows.forEach(function(row){
        data[row.category] = {}; // initialise
    });
console.log('1111111',data,'---------');
});
console.log('2222222',data,'---------');

for (var category in data)
{
    console.log(prefix+'Listing values for on "'+category+'"');
    var values = db.query('SELECT SUBSTRING(date::varchar, 1,7) AS month, sum(amount) FROM cc WHERE category = \''+category+'\' GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1', function(err, data){
        console.log('Got values',data.rows);
    });
}

// -----
console.log(prefix+'Ending connection to database');
//  db.end();

// -----
console.log(prefix+'Ending transaction on server side');
response.end();
```

I get `222222 before 1111111` :/ so my result is sent as empty and then it is filled :( How do I have to do ?

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Of course you got 222222 before 1111111.  That's how async works in node. Your first query starts then node is not waiting for the query to finish, just continues on to print 222222.  That's non-blocking which is a very important feature of node.  If you want to perform the 2nd query after the 1st query is done, you need to put it inside the 1st query's callback which where console.log('1111111',data,'---------'); is.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at promises :https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec. (one good lib for nodejs is q -  [http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/).they](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/%29.they) are really useful in keeping nodejs code coherent and neat in all those callbacks.a must for every nodejs developer.